# Keep the address in the url .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory on my site:

```
/new/
```

I want to access it and redirect to index.php which is one level below, but do not want the address change url, example:

```
accessing: www.site.com/new/ 
check out www.site.com /index.php 
and the url remains www.site.com/new/
```

In htaccess could not do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^novo/*$ /index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

How could he do?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have an index.php file inside the /new directory?

Comment: but I want to keep / new / and want him to go to index.php, it accesses, but does not keep / new /

Comment: o / new is just a redirect, but I want to keep it in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `/new/.htaccess` with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you seriously believe `does not load` type of comments will help your cause. It would really help you if you provide enough information like what was the CSS URL that didn't load. Try to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.